# Git Issue: Can't removed "untracked" sibling directories from git status

Tags: git, github, git-untracked

I have started a new project in a new repo with two other projects and repos in the same local directory.  Git status keeps showing me these other directories (i.e. ../OtherProject) as untracked items.  I can't seem to removed them either in gitignore or by using git clean.  It is annoying because I don't want to see them and is blocking some other commands from running successfully.

Comment: What do you mean by `two other projects and repos in the same local directory`? Could you provide more details?

Comment: I have two other git repo directories in the same parent directory.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out on my own:  It looks like since I had git initialized in the parent directory the tracked and untracked files were based on that and when I thought I was running git commands from a git instance from the local repo the commands were actually based in the parent directory where there was a .git file.